# Side slide menu

Tags: ios, xcode6

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController class]]) {


    SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController*) segue;
    swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc,UIViewController* dvc){

    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
    };

}

}
```

I am calling this to call my different UIs on clicking a particular cell in the table view but they are giving me an error "property performblock not found on type SWRevealViewC ontrollerSegueSetController"

Please help!!! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: **SWRevealViewC ** -- front view or sidemenu or the RootView

Answer (score 1):

yeah same error i have

But in your **SWRevealViewController.h** file at last section remove comment from this code

```
@interface SWRevealViewControllerSegue : UIStoryboardSegue     

@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^performBlock)(
     SWRevealViewControllerSegue* segue, UIViewController* svc,
     UIViewController* dvc );

@end
```

as same in **SWRevealViewController.m** file at last section remove this comment from this code

```
@implementation SWRevealViewControllerSegue  // DEPRECATED

-(void)perform {
    if ( _performBlock )
        _performBlock( self, self.sourceViewController,self.destinationViewController ); 
}

@end
```

I think This is gonna work in your project